# Javascript: How can I access an event's id from a class descriptor from within a JQuery Dialog constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm very new to javascript and jquery, so I apologize if this is a very simple question ahead of time. :)

I'm using JQuery UI's Tabs in a simple webpage, and I was trying to add a double click function to the Tab names which would invoke a JQuery Modal Dialog and allow the user to change the name of the tab.  Since I have a dynamic number of tabs on the page, I don't want to limit the doubleclick function to the specific tab's "id", so I've created a "class".

With what I have so far is within the dblclick function of the class "renameable-tabs". I want to override the text(), but once I'm inside the dialog constructor, $(this) now refers to the dialog box.  I've tried to access the event.target and event.target.id and override the text(), but I just haven't had any luck getting it to work.

Any input/help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

I've put together pretty simple jsfiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/79Evd/

Comment: You cannot successfully mix double-click with single-click on the same element. It's a guaranteed losing battle, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Pointy: Why?  What makes it a "losing battle?"

Comment: It is simply not well supported in current browsers. For one thing, browsers (all of them I think) will give you at least one "click" event too.

Comment: @Pointy - If we have click as well as dblclick event attached to and element then both the events are triggered on click. We have to do a workaround to solve this issue.

Comment: It's a usability nightmare. There's no reason at all to use double-click on a website, and **especially** not on an element that's also got a "click" handler!  It's just a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the dblclick event handler store `this` is a local variable and then you can access it inside the dialog `Add` callback. This is an example of closure where javascript keeps track of all the variables within the scope.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79Evd/3/)**

Comment: Damn, I was going to say call the function and pass this. Don't know why I didn't think of that first.

Comment: @Hurgle - Hope this helped you, make sure you mark this as an answe whenever you can, thanks.